# How to get child element based on parent element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gs_or')
for item in items:
   title_temp = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[2]/h3/a").text
```

In this case,

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/div[2]/h3/a"}
```

this error is occurred.

Comment: Can you share the URL? if not, update the question with HTML.

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML code for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and I think there is one mistake on your expression in xpath. I think you have to erase `.` in xpath expression. So ...

`title_temp = item.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/h3/a").text`

This expression will be work, I think.

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.